# react-data-grid 7.0.0 beta.12 ShowCheckbox not working. How to render a checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I have tried to get showCheckbox to work with no success.
I setup this installed "react-data-grid": "^7.0.0-beta.12",
The Checkbox column simply does not appear.
Can anyone help?

Code that I used in App.js

```
<ReactDataGrid
          columns={this.columns}
          rows={setGlobalMsgList}
          rowsCount={this.props.setGlobalMsgList.length}
          // onRowClick={this.onRowClick}
          onGridSort={this.handleGridSort}
          rowSelection={{
            showCheckbox: true,
            enableShiftSelect: true,
            onRowsSelected: this.onRowsSelected,
            onRowsDeselected: this.onRowsDeselected,
            selectBy: {
              indexes: this.state.selectedIndexes,
            },
          }}
          emptyRowsView={EmptyData}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const columns = [
        SelectColumn,
        { key: 'id' , name: "ID", frozen:true }  ]
```

simply import the SelectColumn from

```
 import {SelectColumn} from 'react-data-grid'
```